# Pythonic way to get list element when expectation is that list contains only a single element?

Tags: python, list, built-in, idioms

I often run into the situation where I am querying some data source that returns a list, however I'm expecting the list to contain only a single element.  Right now I do:

```
el = result_list[0]
```

maybe in a try block in case the list is empty.  But, I don't like it.  What is the best way?  It would be cool to do this:

```
el = result_list.only()
```

And perhaps that could puke if the list is empty or has more than one element.

Comment: Not typically Pythonic to fail on things like that, but if you need to, I would check for len==1 and raise a ValueError if necessary.

Comment: many things (like databases) provide an API to `fetch_one` instead of `fetch_all`, so if said source provides such a method (or you can write one) I'd do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 2 or 3:

```
>>> a, = [1]
>>> a
1

>>> a, = []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack

>>> a, = [1,2,3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

In Python 3, you can also

```
>>> a,*_ = [1,2,3]
>>> a
1
```

Comment: Of course!  Well done, thanks.  I'll accept this in a few minutes.